# Create chart with WPF Chart ToolKit based on the selected ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, combobox

I have a ComboBox with different projects. Based on the value from this combobox, i want the different hours that have been registrered on this project presented in a chart.

The code for the chart I have created:

```
                    <chartingToolkit:Chart Height="262" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="33,0,0,620" Name="columnChart"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="360" BorderBrush="AntiqueWhite" BorderThickness="1">
                    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries 
                        DependentValuePath="Value" 
                        IndependentValuePath="Key" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

The code that "should" populate the list that would create the graph:

```
private void showColumnChart()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int();
        List<ProsjektTime> timeListe = new List<ProsjektTime>();

        foreach (ProsjektTime p in Master.getDC().ProsjektTimes)
        {
            if (p.ProsjektID_FK == prosjekt.ProsjektID)
            {
                timeListe.Add(p);
            }
        }

        foreach(ProsjektTime p in timeListe)
        {
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int(p.TimeTyper.Type,p.AntallTimer));
        }

        try
        {
            columnChart.DataContext = valueList; 
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e) { MessageBox.Show(e+""); }
    }
```

Unfortunately I get the error, "Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk".

However I found out something interesting. If I set the selectedIndex of the ComboBox to a project that has some hours registered on it (not all projects have hours registered on them), then everything works fine. Projects that has hours get presented in the chart and projects without any hours registered also get presented as an empty chart. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Insted of having one dataSourceList and one chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries, I created two lists and two chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries. Heres the code:

```
        private void prosjektTimeGraf()
    {
        int estimerteTimer = 0;
        int registrerteTimer = 0;

        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> estimerListe = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> registrertListe = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        foreach (ProsjektTime p in Master.getDC().ProsjektTimes)
        {
            if (p.ProsjektID_FK == prosjekt.ProsjektID)
            {
                estimerteTimer += p.AntallTimer;
                estimerListe.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(p.TimeTyper.Type, p.AntallTimer));
            }
        }

        foreach (ProsjektTimeBruker ptb in Master.getDC().ProsjektTimeBrukers)
        {
            if (ptb.ProsjektID_FK == prosjekt.ProsjektID)
            {
                registrerteTimer += (int)ptb.AntallTimer;
                registrertListe.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ptb.TimeTyper.Type, (int)ptb.AntallTimer));
            }
        }

        estimerListe.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Totalt", estimerteTimer));
        registrertListe.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Totalt", registrerteTimer));

        try
        {
            espTimer.DataContext = estimerListe;
            regpTimer.DataContext = registrertListe;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e) { MessageBox.Show(e+""); }
    }
```